# Check if string contains at least two alpha chars

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I need to check if a string has at least two alpha characters, like `a1763r` or `ab1244`
I was thinking I would use something like:

```
myString = "a123B";  
myString.Any(char.IsDigit).Count();
```

but I'm using .net 2.0 so this method `Any()` does not exists.

Is there something equivalent?

Comment: Try programming. For example, you might write a loop that checks each character.

Comment: You could use a regular expression...

Comment: But why would he ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know about alpha or what not, but you can count how many characters are digits without Linq like so:

```
string str = "a123B";
int digits = 0;
foreach (char c in str)
    if (char.IsDigit(c))
        digits++;
print(digits); // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple helper function that loops over your string, taking in a minimum threshold to meet.  It returns boolean to match the type of output behavior from `.Any()`

```
public bool ContainsMinAlphaCharacters(string input, int threshold)
{
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var character in input)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(character)) count++;
        if (count >= threshold) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexpressions

two letters: `Regex.IsMatch(myString, "[A-Za-z].*?[A-Za-z]");`

two digits: `Regex.IsMatch(myString, "\d.*?\d");`

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You will have to loop through the string and check if each character is a digit to get the count.